# K-fold Cross-Validation on table in Matlab

Tags: matlab, logistic-regression, cross-validation, categorical-data, naivebayes

I have a Matlab table that contains information on students (numerical and categorical). A sample is given here:

```
School = {'GB'; 'UR'; 'GB'; 'GB'; 'UR'};
School = categorical(School);
Age = [14;14;12;16;19];
Relationship = {'yes'; 'yes'; 'no'; 'no'; 'yes'};
Relationship = categorical(Relationship);
Status = {'ft'; 'pt'; 'ft'; 'ft'; 'ft'};
Status = categorical(Status);
Father_Job = {'pol'; 'ser'; 'oth'; 'ele'; 'cle'};
Father_Job = categorical(Father_Job);
Health = [1;2;3;3;5];
Exam = {'pass'; 'pass'; 'fail'; 'fail'; 'pass'};
Exam = categorical(Exam);

T =
School    Age    Relationship    Status    Father_Job    Health    Exam
______    ___    ____________    ______    __________    ______    ____

  GB      14         yes           ft         pol          1       pass
  UR      14         yes           pt         ser          2       pass
  GB      12         no            ft         oth          3       fail
  GB      16         no            ft         ele          3       fail
  UR      19         yes           ft         cle          5       pass
```

I want to use this data to predict and classify the pass/fail of the exam. I am planning to use the `fitglm` to make a logistic regression, and `fitcnb` to make a Naive Bayes classifier. I know that both methods can handle well categorical variables in Matlab, so there should be no problem using my table as it is, with its categorical variables.

However, I have a problem when I want to use `cvpartition` and `crossvalind` to perform a 10-fold cross-validation. When I try to create indices of my folds, I get the following error: *Error using statslib.internal.grp2idx Subscripting a table using linear indexing (one subscript) or multidimensional indexing (three or more subscripts) is not supported. Use a row subscript and a variable subscript*.

My goal is to perform the following operations:

```
% Column 7 (Exam) is the response variable
X = T(:, 1:6);
Y = T(:, 7);

% Create indices of 5-fold cross-validation (here I get errors)
cvpart = cvpartition(Y,'KFold',5);
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',Y,5);

% Create my test and training sets
for i = 1:5
 test = (indices == i); 
 train = ~test;
 Xtrain = X(train,:);
 Xtest = X(test,:);
 Ytrain = Y(train,:);
 Ytest = Y(test,:);
end

% Fit logistic model
mdl = fitglm(Xtrain,Ytrain,'Distribution','binomial')
```

Would anyone have a take on this please? I know that I can possibly change the categorical variables to numerical ones, but I would rather not. Is there anyway around this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that your data set is just too small.  You have n =5, which isn't even enough to create a non-validated model.

Comment: Hello. The dataset I posted here is just a sample, the one I am working with has 600+ rows and 33 columns. So it shouldn't be the problem.